# Keras Mask-rcnn custom dataset training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I got assigned a project for my thesis where i should code a programm to detect trees (or more specific treetrunks). So I went and took some pictures to create a dataset for deep-learning. I created the annotations file and used a Notebook by Pysource to create the model. The problem now seems that this Notebook only gives me the Keras weights (h5). When i tried to convert the file to Tensorflow (pb), to implement it into my Python program. But it seems the converter needs the config to convert it into TF. I already searched on here for some solutions but the only answer i see it to use model.save() and not model.save_weights(). But i can't find this line of code in the notebook to change it. Is there maybe any other way to convert the keras into tf or any other notebook that gives me the weights+config? Or a way to directly use the Keras weights only in a Python program for instance segmentation without converting it to TF?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend you to post a sample with the code that you are trying out right now, and the output it generates in case it's relevant. That way is easy for others to understand better where you are stuck.

Comment: Why the need to convert to tensorflow? Just load the model using Keras. And more importantly, you did not include any code or link to the notebook you are talking about, without more information, people cannot help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy How can i load the model using Keras? When i use model.load_model() it gives me a error that it needs the Config as well. And model.load_weights() isn't working, because it says that this function doesn't exist in the Model class.  [This](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pysource7/utilities/blob/master/Train_Mask_RCNN_(DEMO).ipynb) is the Notebook i was using.

Comment: The linked notebook does not have any save functionality. If you have a only weights model, you first need to recreate the model architecture and then call load_weights on that model. If you use model.save you will get a model that is loadable with load_model

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Okay I get that! But i am stuck at how I would approach that solution? Do I look for another notebook that uses a save function? Or can i recreate the architecture with the weights alone? And if yes, how?

Comment: The easiest is to call model.save, why not just edit the notebook to add this call?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I already tried this, but i am not able to figure out where to call model.save or what i should replace it with.

Comment: Right after training, before the testing cells. And more importantly, you keep claiming that you do not know, but how did you get the weights file? It is not generated by the notebook anyways.

Comment: Okay I'll try that! I really don't know how, but after the training is finished the model.h5 file is ready to download in the explorer on the left.